# Cupy compiler error when summing over singleton axis

Tags: cupy

My code includes a line where I sum over the first dimension of an array. This works fine if I use an array with non-singleton dimension, for example:

```
test = cp.ones((2, 3, 4))
test1 = cp.sum(test, axis=0)
```

It also works in the following singleton dimension case:

```
test = cp.ones((1, 3, 4))
test1 = cp.sum(test, axis=0)
```

But now if I make the dimension of the second axis also 1, I get an error:

```
test = cp.ones((1, 1, 4))
test1 = cp.sum(test, axis=0)
```

The error is 'nvcc fatal   : Cannot find compiler 'cl.exe' in PATH', which doesn't make sense since I am otherwise able to run CuPy. To add to the confusion, summing over the second axis does not return this error:

```
test = cp.ones((1, 1, 4))
test1 = cp.sum(test, axis=1)
```

I am running CuPy version 11.6.0.

The code works fine in NumPy, and according to what I've posted above the sum function works fine for singleton dimensions. It only seems to fail when applied to the first axis with an adjacent singleton axis.